# Calling cordova module?

Tags: javascript, cordova

I found [this cordova module](https://github.com/jasminpethani/cordova-plugin-musicplayer/blob/master/com.srini.musicplayer/www/musicplayer.js), there are no usage instructions though?

Writing

```
MusicPlayer.init(
        function (msg) {
            console.log("audio completed"+ msg);
        },
        // error callback
        function (e) {
            console.log("Error getting message=" + e);
        }
    );
```

return `Could not load main module: ReferenceError: MusicPlayer is not defined`

The module is exported like `module.exports = new MusicPlayer();`, so the way to call it is that itself?

Trying, `window.cordova.plugins.Musicplay.init();` also gave the same error.

What is the correct way to call this module and use in cordova?

EDIT - This is how the functions are defined

```
var exec = require('cordova/exec');

function MusicPlayer() {}

MusicPlayer.prototype.init = function(successCallback, errorCallback, json) {
    exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "MusicPlayer", "init", [json]);
};    
MusicPlayer.prototype.getMusicList = function(successCallback, errorCallback, json) {
    exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "MusicPlayer", "getMusicList", [json]);
};
..
..
module.exports = new MusicPlayer();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check clobbers target: https://github.com/jasminpethani/cordova-plugin-musicplayer/blob/master/com.srini.musicplayer/plugin.xml#L14-L16

```
<js-module src="www/musicplayer.js" name="musicplayer">
    <clobbers target="musicplayer" />
</js-module>
```

So instance name should be `musicplayer`

```
   musicplayer.init(function (msg) {
        console.log("audio completed"+ msg);
    },
    // error callback
    function (e) {
        console.log("Error getting message=" + e);
    });
```

---

Tips:

- Be sure `MusicPlayer` plugin exists in list when you run `$ cordova plugin list`
- Be sure you call `musicplayer.init` inside:

  `document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){/**/}`

Comment: It worked! If you could tell, what needs to be passed to the [playSong](https://github.com/jasminpethani/cordova-plugin-musicplayer/blob/master/com.srini.musicplayer/www/musicplayer.js#L23) function? I tried with the first value returned from the `getMusicList` and added that as the third argument. But it returns `Invalid action`?

Comment: Well, its not question you asked, but anyways see Android and iOS implementation: https://github.com/jasminpethani/cordova-plugin-musicplayer/blob/master/com.srini.musicplayer/src/android/MusicPlayer.java#L49 . Looks like he didn't implemented it on Android and on iOS there is no params. Sorry

Comment: That was bad ;). Thanks you helped a lot.